# oracle sql nested select in select

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT idemployee, lastname, firstname,
(SELECT namedep FROM department
WHERE numdep = 120) depname
FROM employee
WHERE numdep = 120;
```

what does the statement return?
how does the nested select impact the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a really simple query. Without examples of the tables and the data in them we can't tell you exactly what the query would return but it should be something like this.

idemployee | lastname | firstname | depname

1 | Smith | John | Sanitation

2| Doe | Jane | Sanitation

Breaking it down: SELECT namedep FROM department
WHERE numdep = 120 seems to be getting the department name for department #120. This will then show up in the last column for each row of the main query.

SELECT idemployee, lastname, firstname FROM employee WHERE numdep = 120 seems to be simply selecting the employee id, last name and first name from the employee table for everyone in department 120.

You could write this much more simply as

```
SELECT e.idemployee Employee_ID, e.lastname, e.firstname, d.namedep Department_name
FROM employee e inner join department d on e.numdep = d.numdep
WHERE d.numdep = 120
```

This would return the same results. Would be much safer performance wise. It would also be much easier to change to run for different departments, multiple departments or all departments.

I simply joined the to tables together based on the common column, numdep, and selected what I wanted from the table. I also added aliases (e,d) so I didn't have to type out employee and department to specific which table I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a correlated subquery.  It is more commonly written as an explicit join:

```
SELECT e.idemployee, e.lastname, e.firstname, d.namedep
FROM employee e left join
     department d
     on e.numdep = d.numdep
WHERE e.numdep = 120;
```

These two formulations are not exactly the same, but in this case they probably return the same results.

Comment: could you give me an example of the result ?